# How to rewrite this url in NGINX

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have multiple urls in this manner.

```
http://domain.com/something/static/variable/
```

But now I want to redirect the url above to

```
http://domain.com/anything/static/variable/
```

I tried

```
location /something{
        rewrite ^ http://domain.com/anything$request_uri? permanent;
    }
```

But that redirects to

```
http://domain.com/anything/something/static/variable/
```

How to fix this rewrite rule?

Comment: You may want to check your logs and report back with more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rewrite rule will do the trick:

```
rewrite ^/something/(.+)$ http://domain.com/anything/$1 permanent;
```